# Kotlin overridden onBackPressed() function is never called when Action Bar back button is pressed

Tags: android, kotlin

I've seen this question posed all over the place but I have not seen where anyone has been able to answer why the function doesn't get called.

I've run the app in debug mode with a break point set at the onBackPressed function and it completely ignores it. The compiler even recognizes and changes my red break point into a circle with a line through it.

I have a ContractSelectAdapter with a setOnClickListener passing a selected contract to ContractMenuActivity using putExtra(). Once in the ContractMenuActivity there is a button to open the activity below, UploadImageActivity and while in the activity I want a user to be able to hit the back button to reopen the ContractMenuActivity but within the onCreate function of ContractMenuActivity is a getStringExtra call that causing it to crash because there is no "extra". Which is why I'm trying to use the onBackPressed. In theory it should work perfectly.

I've tried putting a call to the onBackPressed function manually in the onCreate function of UploadImageActivity just to make sure it works and it does. It immediately opens ContractMenuActivity. So the function works it just never gets called for some reason. Extremely frustrating.

the onBackPressed function is at the very end of the UploadImageActivity class (first code excerpt)

Any help would be GREATLY appreciated.

```
class UploadImageActivity : AppCompatActivity() {    

    var prefs: Prefs? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_upload_image)
        prefs = Prefs(this)    
    }

    override fun onBackPressed()
    {
        super.onBackPressed()
        val returnIntent = Intent(this, ContractMenuActivity::class.java)
        returnIntent.putExtra(SELECTED_CONTRACT, prefs!!.rmsAppContractID)
        startActivity(returnIntent)
    }

}
```

---

```
class ContractMenuActivity : AppCompatActivity()
{
    var selectedContract: String = ""
    var prefs: Prefs? = null


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_contract_menu)
        prefs = Prefs(this)

        val btnUploadImage = findViewById<Button>(R.id.btnUploadImage)

        selectedContract = intent.getStringExtra(SELECTED_CONTRACT)
        prefs!!.rmsAppContractID = this.selectedContract


        var contractSelectMsg = "Contract ${prefs!!.rmsAppContractID} selected"
        val duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
        Toast.makeText(this, contractSelectMsg, duration).show()

        btnUploadImage.setOnClickListener {this.openUploadImage()}

    }

    public fun openUploadImage()
    {

        val registered =  prefs!!.rmsAppRegistered
        var message: String

        if(registered)
        {
            val intent = Intent(this, UploadImageActivity::class.java)
            startActivity(intent);
        }
        else
        {
            message = "You must Pair this device before you can upload an image."
            val intent = Intent(this, PostResponseMessageActivity::class.java).apply {
                putExtra(POST_RESPONSE_MESSAGE, message)
            }
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    }

}
```

Parent name in manifest:

```
    <activity
            android:name=".ContractMenuActivity"
            android:label="@string/contractMenuLabel"
            android:parentActivityName=".ContractSelectActivity">

    </activity>
    <activity
            android:name=".UploadImageActivity"
            android:label="@string/uploadImageLabel"
            android:parentActivityName=".ContractMenuActivity">
    </activity>
```

Comment: Is the previous activity the parent on the manifest?

Comment: Well i believe you should save you data from the Intent in onSaveIntance and restore it in onRestoreInstance and not rely on the intent to persist your extra then in onCreate you check is the intent is null if null then this is probably a saved state so you restore it from the bundle.

Comment: Hi @Josh M, welcome to SO. As a suggestion it may be worth to clear up a bit on your post, removing parts that aren't relevant to the specific issue such as the methods to do with uploading the image for instance as it will then make it a bit easier for people who're trying to identify the issue and help you fix it to read your code. :)

Comment: @cutiko ...the previous activity is in fact named as the parent in the manifest. I really appreciate all the suggestions. I was trying to limit the amount of information I provided to only that which was necessary. However, admittedly, I am new to Kotlin and mobile development so I may have missed something or provided too much. Nonetheless I was leading with the Android dev reference which states that you can override the onBackPressed function "to do whatever you want" [Android Dev Reference](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#onBackPressed()).

Comment: Thank you @Mihai I'm going to look into your suggested implementation.

Comment: For now I'm just going to use an "if" statement to check for null extras. If null, I'm skipping over getStringExtra(). No crash on back button pressed using this check. I sure would like to know why the overridden onBackPressed never gets called though.

Answer (score -1):

*super.onBackPressed()*
Will finish the current activity. If you want to do some action after user press back button, You must to past your code to top of *super.onBackPressed()*.

Comment: Thank you...the problem is the overridden function isn't even getting called. I went ahead and made the change to move my code above the _ super.onBackPressed()_ function within the overridden function but it still crashes when I hit the back button because the parent activity isn't receiving the extra from the current activity.